# iPhone SDK and IDE information for windows

Tags: iphone, coronasdk, ipa

Using which softwares and framework we can create iPhone apps, without owning a MAC Os. I downloaded the Adobe builder with flex, since it creates blackberry, iPhone and android app with clicking options. But it takes huge memory space for ipa file or apk file and need adobe to install components in the mobile too. Is that possible to use CORONA sdk? As like ANDROID SDK,ADT PLugin,Eclipse IDE, Specify any specific iPhone SDk and plugins and IDE compatible to windows os?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Even if you're using the Corona SDK you will need a Mac to develop for iOS.

From their [website](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/installation-and-setup-windows):

Corona SDK on Windows only supports building for Android devices. Corona SDK on Mac supports both iOS and Android.

As far as I know, only "pure" cross platform solutions like the Adobe builder or Titanium's [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/) can create iOS apps on windows, but you might still need a Mac to submit your App to the App Store (although you could do this on a friend's Mac, it only takes a few minutes).

If you're serious about iOS development consider buying a Mac. Especially a Mac Mini is a minor investment compared to what the development of a decent application costs.